# Inheritance in Arduino Code

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino

I'm writing some Arduino code and attempting to use inheritance in some classes. I have a class "Actor" (my base class) and a class "Marble" (which inherits from Actor). Here are the header files:

Actor.h:

```
#ifndef Actor_h
#define Actor_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Actor
{
  public:
    Actor();
    void speak();
  private:
};
#endif
```

Marble.h:

```
#ifndef Marble_h
#define Marble_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Actor.h"

class Marble : public Actor {
  public:
    Marble();
    virtual void speak();    
  private:
};
#endif
```

Actor.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Actor.h"

Actor::Actor()
{
}

void Actor::speak() {
  Serial.println("Actor"); 
}
```

Marble.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Marble.h"

void Marble::speak() {
  Serial.println("Marble"); 
}
```

And finally, in the loop function I do:

```
void loop() {
  Marble marble;
  Actor children[2];
  children[0] = marble;

  children[0].speak();
```

Which results in "Actor" being printed.

I discovered this nice link which seems similar to my issue, but the resolution does not seem to work for me:
http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=41884.0

So. It seems like when I create my array of "Actors" and try and stick Marble in there it gets cast to an Actor, or something like that. Problem is, I'll have a few different characters that will all inherit from "Actor" and I'd like an array of them to iterate over and call overridden methods on them.

So, perhaps the problem is how I'm approaching this problem, or maybe there's some syntax errors? I don't know!

Thanks for your help,
Kevin

Comment: shouldn't the `speak` method in `Actor` be marked as `virtual` also?

Comment: There are two errors here, Philip has pointed out the missing `virtual` and Steven has pointed out the fact that you are copying objects instead of referring to them though pointers. You have to fix both to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `speak` as `virtual` in the `Actor` class, not just in the `Marble` class; without that, `Actor::speak` is a *non*-virtual function, so you will always be called in preference to the virtual `Marble::speak`.

For what it's worth, this has nothing to do with the Arduino: it's just a straight C++ issue.

Comment: That's not correct.  In this case that `Marble::speak` is virtual because it derives from a class that declares it virtual.  It also won't fix the problem for reasons I am putting in an answer.

Comment: You're half right in that the code as written won't compile - you can't do `children[0] = marble` as they're of different types. However, changing all that over to pointers still doesn't fix the problem: `Actor::speak` still isn't virtual.

Comment: Try it yourself.  When you declare a method that shares a signature with a virtual method in a parent class, it is itself virtual even if the keyword isn't present.

Comment: You've got the inheritance the wrong way round - the virtual declaration is in the derived class (`Marble`), not the base class (`Actor`); there is no "virtual method in a parent class" in this case.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Did you delete your answer? It was right, you need pointers for polymorphism to work.

Comment: Thank you both! I implemented both of your solutions and it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `children` is an array of type `Actor`.  The line `children[0] = marble` is taking a `Marble` object, converting it to an `Actor` object and copying the results to `children[0]`.  Since the call to `children[0].speak()` is on an `Actor`, you get the `Actor` version.

In order for this to work the way you want, you need to copy a pointer or reference to the object rather than the object itself.  That is, you want something like `Actor* children[2]':

```
Marble marble;
Actor* children[2];
children[0] = &marble;

children[0]->speak();
```

Of course if `children` has scope outside of `loop`, this will fail utterly and you'll need to use `new` to create your marbles.

Better yet, assuming Arduino has the STL, you should use `vector` and `shared_ptr` or something similar.

[Update] As Philip notes, this will also require that the `speak` method in `Actor` be declared virtual.

Comment: As above, this is wrong. `children[0]->speak()` will call the *non-virtual* `Actor::speak`. You really do need `Actor::speak` to be declared `virtual` for this to work. Try the code in [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sj1sbMMd).